# Using Bertini software to determine whether or not a variety is empty

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-algebra, mathematical-software

I have a system of polynomials $f_1,\dots, f_n \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_m]$, and I would like to determine whether the set of solutions to the system $f_1(x)=\dots=f_n(x)=0$ is empty or not. Since the rank of the system is less than $m$, I know that there are no zero-dimensional components. I can of course run a Bertini positive dimensional solve (TrackType:1), which would compute a full numerical irreducible decomposition of the variety cut out by $f_1,\dots, f_n$. This is running quite slowly, though, and I am wondering if there is a more efficient strategy given that I only want to know if the variety is empty or not.

tldr: What is the most efficient way to determine, using Bertini, whether a set of polynomials cuts out the empty set?

(I have tried using Gröbner basis methods, which are actually running *much faster* than Bertini. This is quite discouraging as I thought Bertini is supposed to give more efficiency at the cost of producing a numerical, rather than computational, result).

Comment: Groebner basis method is supposed to be faster. But it can be very slow sometimes.  So you should try systems where the Groebner basis method works slowly. But I doubt that Bertini would work faster in that case. There is essentially one method of solving systems of eqations.

Comment: @dodd Numerical algebra systems like Bertini appear to use completely different techniques from Gröbner bases. The former uses polynomial continuation, whereas the latter uses a generalization of Euclidean division. Surely there are problems for which Bertini is more efficient, otherwise what is the point of losing the computational "proof"? Are you saying that, for the particular problem of determining whether or not a variety is empty, one should expect Gröbner bases to be more efficient? If so, why?

Comment: The behaviour I have observed is for a "baby version" of the system I would actually like to solve. For the system I would actually like to solve, Gröbner basis methods appear not to be terminating in any reasonable amount of time (i.e. not at all, I ran it for a couple days), which is why I am trying Bertini.

Comment: Doesn't Bertini (never used it) produce approximal solutions only? If so, how are you going to show that there are no solutions? As far as I know there is an "art" of speeding up Groebner's method: choose different orders, etc.

Comment: Yes, but there are [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_certification) to certify that a solution exists near an approximated point.

Comment: Perhaps sadly, there is "art" involved in either approach, and getting an answer in reasonable time may take effort. However, the irreducible decomposition is probably overkill, especially if you have some expectation of whether or not your variety it is empty. I'm assuming you expect it is not?

Comment: (For starters, I would try setting the MAXCODIMENSION equal to $n,$ see https://bertini.nd.edu/BertiniUsersManual.pdf)

Comment: @tim actually, I expect that my variety is empty. That is a good idea. Do you think it would be better to work dimension by dimension in this case (WITNESSGENTYPE 2)?Also, I would imagine that I can get away with lowering my precision settings, given my binary objective. Can I use MPType 0? What about adjusting other precision settings like TrackTolBeforeEG, TrackTolDuringEG, SecurityMaxNorm, SliceTolBeforeEG, SliceTolDuringEG, SliceFinalEG, ... ?

Comment: There are so many options, not only for setting these parameters, but choosing homotopies, endgames, etc. I don’t have much (or any) intuition of which are best for my purposes, even having read “Numerically Solving Polynomial Systems with Betini”

Comment: @doremifasolatido I see... The bottleneck you're likely facing is that a large number of paths need to be tracked in order to even heuristically establish that there are no "witness points" in _any_ codimension. "Dimension by dimension" may not be much help here. I don't consider this to be a strong point of homotopy methods / N.A.G. (others may disagree...)

Comment: @doremifasolatido If you go the symbolic route, you don't necessarily need Groebner bases. All you're looking for is a Nullstellensatz certificate, which can be found with a (giant!) linear algebra computation. People have done this sort of thing for the graph coloring problem --- https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/marguile/papers/issac_2015.pdf

Comment: @tim I have not heard of this, and will look into it! Thank you. One more question while I have your ear: My variety is invariant under a certain finite group action (namely, the symmetric group action on tensors). I have therefore looked into using computational invariant theory techniques. As I understand it, the idea is that you find generators for the ring of invariants, and then compute a Gröbner basis for a larger ideal in a larger polynomial ring that contains these generators...

Comment: ... If you use a block monomial ordering between your original variables and new, there is a Gröbner basis for your original ideal sitting inside this new Gröbner basis.

Comment: Naively, I would expect it to be *more difficult* to compute a Gröbner basis for the larger ideal, because there are more variables and more equations, so I was surprised to see this technique. I have seen it mentioned that this technique is useful if you want to find all the points in a zero-dimensional variety, because the new, larger ideal will have fewer points to compute. Is this technique useful beyond this case?

Comment: This group action I assume is just swapping the labels of rank-$1$ factors in some decomposition? The algorithms you're thinking of are likely in Ch 2.6 of Sturmfels' Computational Invariant Theory. "More difficult" is highly likely...

Comment: Yes, those are the algorithms I am referring to. I can swap rank-1 factors, swap subsystems of the same dimension (send $A\otimes B\otimes C$ to $A\otimes C\otimes B$ and so on), and apply local invertibles. I have found that I can "quotient out" by some of these symmetries "by hand" by putting the product tensor factors in row-reduced-echelon form, etc., but others I cannot

Comment: Thanks for your help, @tim, I will try to compute a Nullstellensatz certificate.

Comment: (In case you're curious, I am trying to check a conjecture of mine that appears [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00264). The first unknown case I want to check, in the notation of that paper, is n=7, m=3, and d_1=d_2=d_3=3.)